# R language: Accidental Combining of 2 different variable

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

```
for(i in c(2001:2002)) {
 ontime <- read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"), header = TRUE)
  if(i == 2001) {
    dbWriteTable(conn, "ontime", ontime, append = TRUE)
} else {
dbWriteTable(conn, "ontime", ontime, append = TRUE)
}
}
ontime$date<- 
paste(as.integer(ontime$DayofMonth),'/',as.integer(ontime$Month),'/',as.integer(ontime$Year))

q3test <- sqldf("select ontime.date AS Date, 
            ontime.Month AS MonthArrive, 
            ontime.Year AS YearArrive, 
            COUNT(ontime.diverted) AS diverted
            FROM ontime
            WHERE diverted!='0' AND diverted!=''
            GROUP BY ontime.date
            ORDER BY diverted")
```

[image]

```
q1a <- dbGetQuery(conn,
   "SELECT ontime.DayOfWeek,ontime.DayOfMonth AS DayOfMonthArrive,ontime.Month AS MonthArrive,
    ontime.Year AS YearArrive,ontime.DepTime AS DepTime, AVG(ontime.DepDelay) AS avg_delay
    FROM ontime
    WHERE ontime.Cancelled = 0 AND ontime.Diverted = 0 AND ontime. DepDelay > 0
    GROUP BY DepTime
    ORDER BY avg_delay")
```

[image]

Hi, basically I would like to retrieve the total diverted planes to the dataframe q3test, however,upon doing so, I could only see the data whereby the year from the dates ends with 2002 and not the year 2001 from the ontime table itself, but when I was pulling the data for other purposes, for example, df "q1a", I could clearly both year 2001 and 2002 being pulled, can anyone guide or hint me what is wrong with my code? Next, is there any reason why for my q3test, I could only see the dates for the year 2002 and not 2001. I have check the csv file for 2001 where there is data for diverted

Comment: Odd, you have `if (i == 2001)`, but both blocks (if true and if false) are identical, so it is doing the same thing.

Comment: Your loop overwrites `ontime`, so it will be whatever it was on the last loop - i.e. when i == 2002

Comment: @r2evans Yup, I’m suspecting because each individual file itself is too big, around 0.5GB per year so maybe the Rstudio is unable to display, which is why for other data frame it can show both years, just not the table itself

Comment: @Andrew Gustar Yes I don’t disagree that it might only read the 2002 file but if that is the case, my data frame q1a would not have been able to read 2001 datas, or is there better way of doing this?

Comment: The loop correctly creates the database from which you read `q1a`, but the data frame `ontime` is just the final CSV file read in by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

basically i solve my problem and use the following codes so that my ontime table would be able to read 2 or more different data from different file

```
ontime <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/chanw/Desktop/ST2195/st2195_project/R-Project/datas",    
                   pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
lapply(read_csv) %>%                                           
bind_rows

dbWriteTable(conn, "ontime", ontime)
```